# Why has the PGN viewer (replayer) stopped working?

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, pgn-viewer

It seems that the chess diagrams have stopped working throughout the site. For example, when viewing [this question](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/39117/why-is-forking-the-king-and-rook-a-blunder-in-this-halloween-gambit-line), now I see the following instead of the diagrams:

[image: Screenshot]

It seems that the issue affects all questions and answers with diagrams. I also tried on a different browser as well as on my phone, and I see the same issue.

Is this a known issue, and when will it be fixed?

---

If anyone is interested in looking at the code for the replayer, it is here: https://github.com/andrewphoy/chess-replayer

Comment: MacBook, Google Chrome, doesn't work for me either.

Comment: I see some errors in the browser console; I'm pretty sure this is related to the [JavaScript migration](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/372590/295232).

Comment: @Glorfindel I posted a question on Meta SE regarding this issue:  [The PGN Viewer (replayer) stopped working on Chess Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/375815/the-pgn-viewer-replayer-stopped-working-on-chess-stack-exchange)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost 24  hours later, it appears to be working just fine. I suspect a blip somewhere in the system. However, until a higher-up pinpoints the true answer, we do not know.

Update: Per @hb20007's comment, I quote
moderator #Benjamin Hodgson's comment on [SE Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/375815/the-pgn-viewer-replayer-stopped-working-on-chess-stack-exchange?noredirect=1#comment1252636_375815) page:  "I think it was a Webpack bug. The chess code is set up to be loaded dynamically by the Webpack runtime system, but it had also been configured as an (unused) entry point in the Webpack config. As far as I know that's meant to be supported, and I couldn't reproduce it when I ran the build on my machine, but removing the entry point for the chess code does seem to have fixed the issue."

Comment: Check this comment for a (technical) explanation of how the bug was fixed: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/375815/the-pgn-viewer-replayer-stopped-working-on-chess-stack-exchange?noredirect=1#comment1252636_375815